# What are core.mountd.######### files? OpenSolaris

Tags: files, opensolaris, core-dump

I and gaining an ever expanding list of of core.mountd.12009999475 type files in my root directory?  What are these? Can I just delete them?

What causes them to be created?

Answer (score 2):

That's called a core file. When a process crashes (in this case, mountd) the system makes a copy of the process's memory space (core) and saves it to disk for later analysis by an administrator (you).

You can safely delete them. To disable them, use `coreadm -d process`.
(Note: That's literally the word "process", don't put the name of a process there.)

Read more about core files at http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/manage_core_dump.html